# Execute a host system command and pass the result as build arg in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building a `docker-compose.yml` file that builds my custom `Dockerfile` and I would need to execute a bash command on my host system first, then the pass the results as build argument for the `Dockerfile`.

Here is an example in practice:

`Dockerfile`:

```
#...
ARG SSH_KEY_BASE64
RUN echo "Build SSH_KEY_BASE64: $SSH_KEY_BASE64"
#...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
#...
version: '3.4'

services:
  container:
    container_name: my-container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        SSH_KEY_BASE64: ${SSH_KEY_BASE64_COMMAND}
    env_file: .env
#...
```

`.env`:

```
SSH_KEY_BASE64_COMMAND=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey | base64)
```

At the moment the value of `$SSH_KEY_BASE64` in the `Dockerfile` is unresolved and it prints just `$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey | base64)`, **but I want it to evaluate that command and print the base64 of the content of my key**.

I would like to avoid to manually run `$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey | base64)` before running `docker-compose up --build` that's why I'm asking for an automatic way to do that.

What options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: I reproduced your example with an `ubuntu` Docker image and the output `Build SSH_KEY_BASE64: $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey | base64)` was printed

Comment: @NPinheiro sorry my bad, I edited the question. I actually want `docker-compose` to evaluate that command and return the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose doesn't support this syntax, and can't directly execute commands on the host system.  The only [substitution syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) it supports are `$VARIABLE`, `${VARIABLE}`, `${VARIABLE:-default}`, and `${VARIABLE:?error}` environment variable expansion syntaxes, and that only in the main `docker-compose.yml` file.  The values in an [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) file aren't interpreted or expanded at all.

In most cases you don't actually want to build an image that depends on the specific host system it's built on; an image is intended to be reused in multiple environments.  In the particular case of an ssh key it's particularly dangerous to pass it as an `ARG` since it can be pretty easily extracted from the final image (`docker-compose run container cat /root/.id_rsa`).  You might need to do whatever operation needs the ssh key (for example, an authenticated `git clone`) on the host system outside of Docker.

The only workaround is to set a host environment variable and reference that instead, but it's probably better to get rid of the `ARG` entirely.